# Using CMD on Very Old PC Keyboard During Boot

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

I use a circa-1987 IBM Model M keyboard (with a PS/2 to USB adapter) on my 2011 Mac Mini.  For the most part it works well, after some tweaks in System Preferences and third party software.

However, one thing I can't figure out is whether I can send the <kbd>Command</kbd> signal during boot.  This would be helpful for booting into recovery mode, etc. On newer PC keyboards I could just use the Windows key, but this old beast doesn't have that.

I'd rather not have to keep another keyboard around just for this purpose, although that's not the end of the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you're out of luck. I don't know exactly what sorts of tweaks you've used to get a command key in OS X, but they're almost certainly at the OS level, not on the hardware or firmware level. The [EFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface) boot loader can't read these tweaks, so unless the keyboard itself can directly send the command key signal, you're out of luck.

The only thing I can think of is some sort of hardware device that would stand in between the keyboard and the Mac and spit out modified key codes if given the proper input. However I don't know of any such product. Perhaps something could be hacked up using an [Arduino](http://arduino.cc) or something similar, but it would be a fairly substantial project.

I think you're best off just getting a cheap keyboard with a windows or command key and keeping it in a drawer for the few occasions when you do need it.

Answer (score 0):

As per comment I searched and discovered that Mac has inbuilt possibility to use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as <kbd>command⌘</kbd>.
[image]

**Old answer:**
I also have a model M (but this applies to any Winkeyless keyboard) but since it is hooked to a MacBook Pro I don't need the <kbd>command⌘</kbd> key for boot but I needed a <kbd>command⌘</kbd> for all the other functions, and since Model M doesn’t have a <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> I cannot use it.

I thought it is impossible, searching on **Ask Different** always this question came first, and no other solution and since I found a solution to use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as <kbd>command⌘</kbd> using
[Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) and import [complex-modification rule from site](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=change%20caps_lock%20command#search-result) this specific rule: ***Change caps_lock to command*** like in image below, I thought was good to post an answer that is probably relevant to modern day MacBook Pro users:

[image]

Make sure you have installed Karabine Elements [following all the steps including Reset and give access for the keyboard and all other steps.](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/getting-started/installation/)

Comment: Is this better than using MacOS's built in options for swapping caps lock and command?

Comment: @ChrisHerbert Is that possible, can you link to that?

Comment: @ChrisHerbert I found Modifier Keys

Comment: @ChrisHerbert I am new to OS X and posted the obvious answer for people that may be in my rookie situation, thanks for pointing out.