# 2009 MacBook Pro does not respond to the Option/Command keys on boot up

Tags: keyboard, startup

I want to flash my 4.1 to 5.1. I then want to turn off SIP. No matter what I do, different keyboards tried, different USB ports, nothing I do will let me boot off a USB drive, or into OS recovery or OS Utils.

Comment: How did you create the USB you're trying to boot off of?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a USB keyboard and have tried each port in a row, then the USB / logic board are the problem.

Even a PC keyboard will work to option boot - so even a PS/2 keyboard will work.

- [Using CMD on Very Old PC Keyboard During Boot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71493/using-cmd-on-very-old-pc-keyboard-during-boot)

As above, only a quite rare keyboard won’t work with modifier keys that don’t work on Mac firmware.